# Why I use selenium to copy the xpath but get nothing?

Tags: python, selenium

### Here is my code I want to download the image search result of the Google.

[This is a link of Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wallpaper&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwj5r4Tc6fvUAhWJQD4KHeJHDugQsAQIOQ&biw=1920&bih=974#imgrc=_)

For example I want to get the first result of it.

[image]

I use the code below to click the first image and it works.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='rg_s']/div[1]/a/img")[0].click()
```

And then I get the result like this: 
[image]

I want to download the origin image. So I use

```
img_urllist = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='irc_cc']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/a/img")
```

But I get a **NoneType** thing here. I don't know why.The **xpath** is correct. Why I get a NoneType.

### This is the error msg I get :

[image]

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from binascii import a2b_base64
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import json
import urllib2
import sys
import time
import re

# adding path to geckodriver to the OS environment variable
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.getcwd()
download_path = "dataset/"

def main():
    searchtext = "wallpaper"
    num_requested = 10

    if not os.path.exists(download_path + searchtext.replace(" ", "_")):
        os.makedirs(download_path + searchtext.replace(" ", "_"))

    url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+searchtext+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)

    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
    extensions = [ "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif" ]
    img_count = 0
    downloaded_img_count = 0


    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='rg_s']/div[1]/a/img")[0].click()
    img_urllist = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='irc_cc']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/a/img")

    print img_urllist
    img_urllist[0].click()

    print "Total downloaded: ", downloaded_img_count, "/", img_count
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below xpath. I tried inspecting the element and found xpath different than yours

```
img_urllist = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='irc_cc']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/a/img")
```