# How to know a certain operation is done on the web is done in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

### Update

I change my code to this base on the first answer,tnx a lot. 
But the code will get the **file not found error**

But the png file is at the same path with the python script. Why it can't find the file ?

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = "http://zhcn.109876543210.com/"

driver.get(url)
input_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#container input[type="file"]')
input_field.send_keys('save.png')
```

## input_field.send_keys('C:/MyPython/DownloadGooglePic/save.png') # abosulte path not work either.

```
submit_upload_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#postfiles')
submit_upload_button.click()

wait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.ok>img')))
print("upload done")
```

---

I use python and selenium to simulate the upload image file and get the OCR result from the [web](http://zhcn.109876543210.com/). Here is a problem.
Here is my code. I use `time.sleep(30)` to wait for the ocr done which must be a bad idea. So I want to know how to know the ocr is done here. I want to be notified when the ocr is done, so I can find the link in the page and download the file from the link.

The image means that I should wait for the ocr done.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from binascii import a2b_base64
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import json
import sys
import time
import re
import keyboard
import time

# adding path to geckodriver to the OS environment variable
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.getcwd()
download_path = "dataset/"

def main():
    url = "http://zhcn.109876543210.com/"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)


    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"

    driver.find_elements_by_id("selectfiles")[0].click()

    filename = '6月12日合同扫描件.jpg'
    keyboard.write(filename, delay=0)
    time.sleep(3) 
    keyboard.press_and_release('alt+o')
    driver.find_elements_by_id("postfiles")[0].click()

    time.sleep(30)

    lista = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    for i in lista:
        try:
            print(i.get_attribute('href'))
        except :
           pass
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[OCR Link](http://zhcn.109876543210.com/)

Comment: Lee I would suggest you to first investigate what happens when file get recognised any change in the template in that page or some new field appears. If so then proceed accordingly

Answer (score 1):

When file uploaded successfully you can see "OK" icon as on below image

[image]

You can add [`ExplicitWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to get the moment when icon appears on page with following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = "http://zhcn.109876543210.com/"

driver.get(url)
input_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#container input[type="file"]')
input_field.send_keys(filename)
submit_upload_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#postfiles')
submit_upload_button.click()

wait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.ok>img')))
print("upload done")
```

Note that you can handle file upload by sending path to file as string to `<input type="file">` element- you don't need to click file upload button and handle dialog window

Comment: Tnx for your help, I will try it letter, can you help me with this question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082905/why-i-use-selenium-to-copy-the-xpath-but-get-nothing